# Why is there some twist existed on my skeleton for 0 rotation?

Tags: animation, bones, bvh

I have generated a bvh file with manually defined skeleton. I find some degree of bone twist exists on every frame. Even when all Euler angles are set as 0, the visualization still exhibits some weird bone twists. I find giving the standard skeleton a global rotation would change the alignment in the visualization. Does it mean the skeleton I defined is done in a wrong way?

I'd like to make it look like figure 2. The problematic bvh file are [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bKzjbc5uPRigFTjc787vimffLrxR0kvC?usp=sharing), f1.bvh is a short version with a single frame; the other is the full animation I generated with deep learning.

I have tried to align the bone to a armature axis as @moonboots suggests like in figure 3 (thanks!) However, doing this also changes my motion in figure 4. Selected is my original pose, and I have aligned two legs and one arm.

Edit: OK, after I global rotate the entire standard skeleton with script, everything seems fine now. figure 5. The modified file is [walk3_subject5_out_100_2_fix_v2.bvh](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cW_bdQdwXPGKxLaK03_zNWaPpZympBVx/view?usp=share_link). Still have no clue why would that remove the twist.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't import the walk bvh, but the default armature has its bone incorrectly rotated, maybe it's your problem here, you need to align the bones with the armature axis, for example select the legs and Shift N > Global X Axis

Comment: @moonboots Hi, thank you very much for the fast response! I have updated my file, hope this time it can be loaded correctly. Anyway, I have followed your advice and edit the bones and align them with the armature axis.(figure3) However, It would also change the my motion data.(figure4)

Comment: Yes because the bones rotate according to their new orientation, they need to be correctly orientated from the beginning, or I may miss something...

Comment: I have rotate the entire skeleton using a global rotational matrix, making it lying on the ground (last pic). It seems it fixed the problem.

Comment: I don't quite understand to be honest. Why would each bone in skeleton of figure 3 [file link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a6zraBwT9vO3xLW1CTSlM_X__DQO29aj/view?usp=share_link) has the correct orientation? Why would different global orientation cause problem in my case? Thank you for the help@moonboots

Comment: Your problem is hard to follow, and Blender Stack Exchange is not really made for complicated problems, maybe you should follow some basic tutorials about rigging, armatures and so on?

Comment: Any suggestion of basic tutorial. I am from deep learning and cs background, I have zero experience of this. Thanks@moonboots

Comment: Darrin Lile and Sebastian Lague have made good tutos on rigging imho, it was for 2.7 but it hasn't changed a lot, maybe take a look?